# Mac OS X - bash default pathname expansion or bug

Tags: macos, bash, glob

I'm trying to run the following line of script in bash on Mac OS X 10.6.4 (from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4045887/macvim-and-mercurial-check-in/4045958#4045958)):

```
$ export EDITOR='mvim -f -c "au VimLeave * !open -a Terminal"'
```

Alas, what I get is something unexpected:

> $ echo $EDITOR
> mvim -f -c "au VimLeave Desktop Documents Downloads Library Movies Music Pictures Public Sites bin !open -a Terminal"

The expected output would be:

> $ echo $EDITOR
> mvim -f -c "au VimLeave * !open -a Terminal"

The way to fix this to this is to set `noglob`, i.e. run `set -f` immediately prior to the `export` assignment. However, the question at hand is whether this is the expected behaviour on Mac OS X because (because `noglob` is unset by default, i.e. `set +f`) or because there is a bug in `bash` on Mac OS X.

The version of bash is:

```
$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 3.2.48(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin10.0)
Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
```

There may be some assistance by way of page 329 of `A practical guide to Unix for Mac OS X users`: "Unless noglob (page 320) is set, the shell performs [pathname expansion] when it encounters an ambiguous file reference--a token containing any of the unquoted characters &, ?, [, or ].". However because the `*` being globbed is within quotes, the question remains: Is the behaviour a default setting of bash, or a bug?

This is just a curiosity, but I'd be grateful for any thoughts and input you may have.

Brian

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your `EDITOR` variable *is* set correctly. You can see this if you execute:

```
echo "$EDITOR"
```

Have a look at the following transcript:

---

```
pax> export EDITOR='mvim -f -c "au VimLeave * !open -a Terminal"'

pax> echo $EDITOR
mvim -f -c "au VimLeave SecretCiaDoc.txt NsaEchelonKeys.txt !open -a Terminal"

pax> echo "$EDITOR"
mvim -f -c "au VimLeave * !open -a Terminal"
```

---

Your problem lies not with the `set` statement but with your `echo`. The `set` will not expand the `*` because it's contained within single quotes but doing an `echo` without quotes *will* expand it.

This in no way affects programs which use the environment variable.

---

Based on your comment:

> This is still weird: that `*` is still within quotes (the double quotes) for the `echo` command. `a='abc "*" xyz'; echo $a` does not expand for me in either bash or dash; in fact, it includes the quotes as the second argument.

Watch this:

```
pax> a='abc "*" xyz' ; echo $a
abc "*" xyz

pax> a='abc "* xyz' ; echo $a
abc "* xyz

pax> a='abc " * xyz' ; echo $a
abc " SecretCiaDoc.txt NsaEchelonKeys.txt xyz

pax> touch '"hello' ; a='abc "* xyz' ; echo $a
abc "hello xyz
```

See what's happening. It's not treating the `"` as anything special, just another character. The reason why it expands for your `EDITOR` is because it's on its own. When you use `"*"`, it's actually trying to expand files that begin and end with `"` - you can see that in my last example above.

Comment: This is still weird: that \* is *still within quotes* (the double quotes) for the echo command.  `a='abc "*" xyz'; echo $a` does not expand for me in either bash or dash; in fact, it includes the quotes as the second argument.

Comment: Note I'm not testing on OS X but I am running bash 4.1.5; it seems like there's probably a different shell option that explains this behavior, but I can't find it.

Comment: @Roger, check out the update, hopefully that will explain it.

Comment: Ah, that explains it! (And shopt -s failglob is very useful here.)